# poll ASP application variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the code below to poll application variables in ASP.  The code below works the first time meaning when I first start the page, if the Application("NFC")= 1 ,  The IF statement in the setinterval function will catch it, display the alert and then reload the page.  The issue is now that the page is running, if another page sets the Application variable back to 1 again, the if statement below will no longer trigger.  If I refresh the page manually, it will work again once.

I placed in the Head and the Body and the same results.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to get this working?

This code is to minimize accessing a database. I am currently accessing the database every 20 seconds now and this will allow me to only access the database if the application variable has changed, polling the variable every 5 seconds.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you JOHN...

```
<%
If request.querystring("R") = "reset" then 
Application("NFC") = 0 
response.redirect("test2.asp")
end if
%>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       setInterval(function(){

   if('<%= Application("NFC")%>'== '1'){
     alert('NFC has changed. This alert is for testing and is not needed in final code');
     self.location='test2.asp?R=reset';
      }

    }, 5000);

  </script>
```

Comment: that value is set in stone once it leaves the ASP server as var as JS is concerned. you have to ajax in that url to get new values. if that value has changed, then make another ajax to the DB.

Comment: Thank u for the response...  are you aware of a simple routine in AJAX or whatever to acquire the current application variable.  In searching the internet, I am finding extensive code for session variables, but nothing for application variables.  Can you point me to any examples?

Answer (score 0):

basically any ajax routine will do, jQuery is more robust than this modern browser example:

server.asp:

```
 <%= Application("NFC")%>
```

client.js:

```
function aGet(turl, callback) {
    var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHRt.onload= callback;
    XHRt.open("GET", turl, true);
    XHRt.send("");
}

aGet("server.asp", function(e){
  alert(e.target.responseText);
});
```

once you see how, it's simple, but it's hard to search for. that's got to be about the simplest back-end code ever...
kudos on using the under-used yet awesome RAM cache that is the Application object: if used correctly, it can enable great real-time apps dues to the negligible cost of pinging that simple server page.

Comment: This is perfect and simple.  It worked like a charm. dandavis, you are the man. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: glad it worked out for you and that you're using {Application}.

Comment: After testing, I have found that this works in Firefox but not in IE. The response in IE is always -0- .  Any Idea?  Thanks, John

Comment: yeah, IE is not a modern browser. just look for a jQuery ajax demo and replace the demo's URL with yours to get a better ajax routine that will work anywhere; mine was more of a quick and dirty demo than production code.